# How do I detect when a user switches between websites/store views?

Tags: multistore, store-view, scope-switcher

I'm trying to work out how to detect when a user has left a store view and landed on another.

Basically I have website A with a domain of `magento.com.localhost` and website B with a domain of `magento.co.uk.localhost`.

On each website I have a store switcher. So if I'm on website A I have a link that looks like `magento.co.uk.localhost/category?___store=gb&___from_store=us` and when I click it I go to a different store view, but want to be able to track when this happens.

I figured the easiest way to do this is to use `Mage::app()->getRequest()` to get `$_GET['from_store']` but this variable doesn't seem to exist due to the nature of the url rewrites.

Is there a Magento specific way to detect when a user has landed on the site from a different store code and how can I access that store code.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can listen on the `controller_action_predispatch` event.

in **config.xml**:

```
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <controllerActionPredispatch>
                <class>Vendor_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>controllerActionPredispatch</method>
                </controllerActionPredispatch>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
    </events>
```

in **Observer.php**:

```
<?php
class Vendor_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerActionPredispatch($observer)
    {
        if($switch = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('___from_store')) {
            $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
            /* do your tracking here */
        }
    }
}
```