# Magento capture switch store event

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need to create an observer for the event of store switching. Basically I need to do some stuff when the visitor switches storeviews/stores. Where can I find that event?

I cant identify it in this [Cheatsheet](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the general event `controller_action_predispatch`.
This is dispatched for every page called.
In your observer you can check if there is a parameter called `___store` sent through GET.
If it is, then the store is switched.
You can get that value like this:

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('___store');
```

Of course you may get false positives if someone simply adds that parameter in GET manually, but I don't know any other method to check this.
There is no special event dispatched when the store is changed / initialized because this happens very early in the request. It happens in `Mage_Core_Model_App::_checkGetStore` that is called in the `init` method in the same class.

Comment: Thank you Marius. I discovered the same solution as you gave me, in question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18133/how-do-i-detect-when-a-user-switches-between-websites-store-views and solved my problem in no time. So your solution works. You gave it in the other question too. Thanks